# Saving an astropy.convolution kernel to a file

Tags: python, astropy

I have created a convolution kernel using astropy.convolution.Gaussian2DKernel.  I can plot the kernel, but I can't figure out how to save it as a .fits image.  (Galfit needs it later in the workflow.)

```
from astropy.convolution import Gaussian2DKernel
plt.imshow(kernel)
kernel = Gaussian2DKernel(4)
plt.imshow(kernel)
fits.writeto('test.fits', kernel)
```

It plots just fine, but returns an error:

> KeyError: 'Data must be a numpy array.'

How can I save a discretization of the kernel as a .fits file?

Comment: You can create an answer for your own question if you resolved it.

Answer (score 3):

Aha!  I changed the last line to:
    fits.writeto('test.fits', kernel.array)

Comment: Your original attempt probably also would have worked if the `Kernel` class had an `__array__` method (this is magic method that tells Numpy code how to treat an object as an array if it isn't already one).  It's possible some fixes are needed on the `astropy.io.fits` end too to recognize objects that aren't arrays but that can be converted to one.  Worth raising an issue about at https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues IMO.  It's only a minor UI enhancement, but worthwhile I think.